# Boot to two different systems (including hardware) from a single drive

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, bios, uefi

I've been using a SSD with Windows 10 which boots in UEFI/GPT mode on my laptop. For a while I decided to switch to my desktop PC which has no SSD of it's own. In order to improve responsiveness of the PC I want to install Arch Linux on that SSD alongside Win10. The problem is that my PC can only boot in BIOS mode. I'm aware that Windows 10 cannot boot in BIOS/GPT mode, while Linux can.

So is this possible to dual boot into **Win10 on UEFI laptop**, and **Linux on BIOS PC**, if the drive is using GPT? Can **GRUB** do it? Or should I look to other boot-managers like **rEFInd**? Or is it better to just make an image of the Win10 system and boot partitions, and format the drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, this is possible as long as the BIOS bootloader supports GPT partition tables. (You will use two completely separate bootloaders – the UEFI one and the BIOS one will live in different places and won't interact at all.)

- GRUB has the same partition table support regardless of platform – it can use `part_gpt` on BIOS systems as well as UEFI systems.

  However, before running 'grub-install' you will need to create an additional "BIOS boot partition" to hold the 'core' GRUB image. (This is *not* the same as an EFI System Partition.) See the relevant [Arch Linux wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#BIOS_systems).
- Syslinux also has an alternative BIOS bootsector (`gptmbr.bin`) which understands GPT partition tables. Just as the regular Syslinux bootsector requires your Linux /boot partition to have the "active" flag, the GPT-capable Syslinux bootsector requires the /boot partition to have the "Legacy BIOS Bootable" attribute (bit 2) set on it. See the relevant [Arch Wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Syslinux#GUID_partition_table).

  *(Yes, the "Active" flag exists on GPT disks... just not for use with UEFI firmware.)*
- rEFInd is an UEFI bootloader and won't run on BIOS systems at all.

Comment: So I finally tried it out and apparently it works. I booted from Arch live environment, followed the instructions and created 3 partitions: 10MiB (overkill tho) for GRUB located before Windows UEFI partition, root partition, and swap. I then installed base Arch packages, chrooted to the mounted root, downloaded GRUB package and installed GRUB. After reboot I selected the SSD in BIOS and it booted into Arch successfully. I haven't checked yet, but I assume that Win10 instance is safe since the entire process didn't touch any of its partitions. Thank you!

Comment: Actually Arch was especially helpful in this regard, because one has to install the bootloader manually. I'm not sure whether such thing would have been possible using graphical installation interface like in Manjaro or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official
[Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463525.aspx),
all its OSs starting from Windows Server 2003 SP1 support volumes with GPT markup as **data disks**. However, only 64-bit Windows versions installed on motherboards
supporting the new UEFI specification are able to **boot** from a GPT volume.
Thus, it is not possible to install or boot Windows from a GPT disk on computers with
classic BIOS firmware.

There are several workarounds that allow you to boot Windows 10/7 x64 on BIOS
from a GPT disk. One such is to use a boot disk containing DUET
(Developer’s UEFI Environment) emulating EFI. In this configuration,
the BIOS boots from the installed SYSLINUX, which loads the UEFI emulator (DUET).
DUET, in turn, calls the standard Windows bootloader `bootx64.efi`.
Also, it is possible to convert your disk into hybrid MBR with the Linux tool `gdisk`.
However, in both cases the procedure is rather complicated and requires
advanced knowledge of Linux.

A simpler method is to use a small USB flash drive or an SD card (64 MB at least)
formatted as MBR, on which small Windows Boot Manager (bootmgr) is placed.
This bootable USB flash drive provides initial boot and transfers control to the
bootloader of the main system located on the GPT volume.
Your BIOS needs to support boot from a USB flash drive or an SD-card.
This way, the booting of both x86 and x64 Windows version in BIOS-based systems
is possible.

If the latest method suits your needs, for details see the article
[Booting Windows 7 / 10 from GPT Disk on BIOS (non-UEFI) systems](http://woshub.com/booting-windows-7-from-a-gpt-disk-using-bios-firmware-non-uefi/).

Comment: Thank you for the article! I have no intent for booting into Win10 from my BIOS machine, I only want to install and use Linux on it. I am just extra catious to not break Win10 in the process so I might later plug the SSD back to my UEFI laptop and keep using it.

Comment: If the SSD is smaller than 2 TB, you could get by with formatting it as MBR.